# Why does heating glucose in the excess of HI produce n-hexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Alcohols react with acid halides such as $\ce{HI}$ to create alkyl halides, as such:

$$\ce{C2H5OH + HX → C2H5X}$$

However, this doesn't seem to be the case with *glucose*, as the entire chain is reduced to an alkane instead. Is this due to the steric hindrance factor of the large chain or perhaps the aldehydic group attached to it?

An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Iodine is somewhat special among halogens, in that it falls off easily.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Even though Iodine is a great leaving group, can it be replaced with a hydrogen?

Comment: Leaving is irrelevant; falling off is another story.